# How to implement material-ui tabs with More dropdown (as shown in documentation screenshot)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am looking to implement a `Tabs` component containing lots (7-9) `Tab` components for a desktop view.  I do not want to use the scrollable tabs when it exceeds the viewport width on the `Tabs`, instead I want the extra `Tab` items to be in a **More** dropdown menu just like the example docs show below: 
[image: dropdown example]

### Questions:

1. What is the intended implementation to achieve this?  I actually would like the exact same functionality they describe as well where when I click an item from the dropdown above (for example, books), that will swap positions with the `Tab` directly to the left of the **More** dropdown, as shown in this screenshot from the doc:

[image: books selected]

2. Specifically, is the **More** dropdown a [Tab](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs) component, or a [Dropdown Menu](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu) component?
3. When using, how does selecting a tab/option from the More Dropdown work by default?  (ex: will the selected tab then get moved to the visible tab portion, just like the screenshots?).  Or does this need to be done manually to achieve that result?
4. Lastly, are there links to any examples of this usage?

Answer (score 3):

Late, but it may help someone.

I was able to achieve dropdown within tabs by using the popover component.

https://codesandbox.io/s/436906013w

It has three tabs - One, Two and Three. Clicking on Tab 'Three' will perform the normal tab change. Clicking on the dropdown arrow next to tab 'Three' will provide the additional options.

It is not an exact solution to the question but can be achieved with a similar approach.

Answer (score 1):

I created logic with MUI List, u can customize it with MUI tabs.
I calculate the width al all items and check if we have enough space, if not I added more button with dropdown and added the rest inside. Be aware that now it does not recalculate if the width or length of items changed

https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-paper-941ff?file=/src/App.js

[image]